# Representing an electrical circuit in Haskell

Tags: sql, haskell

Consider the following (simplified) model of an electrical circuit in
MySQL:

```
create table circuit (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(30) not null
);
create table device (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  circuit_id int not null references circuit (id),
  chip varchar(30) not null,
  primary key (id)
);
create table pin (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  device_id int not null references device (id),
  name varchar(10) not null unique,
  unique (device_id, name)
);
create table wire (
  circuit_id int not null references circuit (id),
  pin1_id int not null unique references pin (id),
  pin2_id int not null unique references pin (id),
  primary key (pin1_id, pin2_id)
);
```

As an example, consider the (somewhat pointless) circuit of two
resistors connected in a loop:

```
        RES
    +---/\/\/--+
    |   A   B  |
    |          |
    |   RES    |
    ----/\/\/--+
        B   A
```

Using the database structure I described earlier, this could be
represented as:

```
insert into circuit (name) values ('example');
set @c = last_insert_id();

insert into device (circuit_id, chip) values (@c, 'RES');
set @r1 = last_insert_id();
insert into pin (device_id, name) values (@r1, 'A');
set @a1 = last_insert_id();
insert into pin (device_id, name) values (@r1, 'B');
set @b1 = last_insert_id();

insert into device (circuit_id, chip) values (@c, 'RES');
set @r2 = last_insert_id();
insert into pin (device_id, name) values (@r2, 'A');
set @a2 = last_insert_id();
insert into pin (device_id, name) values (@r2, 'B');
set @b2 = last_insert_id();

insert into wire (circuit_id, pin1_id, pin2_id) values
  (@c, @b1, @a2), (@c, @b2, @a1);
```

How would I represent this kind of structure in Haskell? It will *not* be tied to a database--the SQL was just so I could precisely define the structure I'm trying to represent.

Comment: I know that your gut response is to expect an attempt at a solution, but that's actually a bad idea here. I've asked a similar question before (stemming from the same confusion) where I made an attempt at a solution, and somehow that derailed all the answers into discussing specifics of my (bad) implementation. I'm looking for how *other* people would do it, not how I would do it.

Comment: You might look at the lava stuff on Hackage: [1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xilinx-lava) [2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/kansas-lava) [3](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/york-lava) [4](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/chalmers-lava2000).

Comment: @DanielWagner: Thanks. I'll read through those for inspiration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `pin` table resembles an adjacency list of a graph, so I'd use a graph library - `Data.Graph` or `Data.Graph.Inductive`.

Comment: For libraries, package names are more helpful than module names. In this case I think [fgl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl) is the most complete and performant choice (and probably the one referred to by this answer).

Comment: @DanielWagner: It looks like `Data.Graph` is from [containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) and `Data.Graph.Inductive` is from [fgl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl).

Comment: @Snowball: that's correct.  `Data.Graph` is fine for basic stuff, but fgl is much more full-featured.